# Pywinauto menu_select and click function is not working for an application at my office

Tags: pywinauto

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application

# Run a target application
app = Application().start("C:\ProgramFiles\BatonMediaPlayer\BatonMediaPlayer.exe")
time.sleep(5)

# Select a menu item
print app.BatonMediaPlayer.Children()
print "app.BatonMediaPlayer.SetFocus()", app.BatonMediaPlayer.SetFocus()
time.sleep(1)

app.BatonMediaPlayer.menu_select('Help->About')
```

Comment: Did you try running your script as Administrator? Are these controls visible to `Spy++` or `Inspect.exe`? Please provide more details.

Comment: I was not running it as an admin but when i did IsActive() is showing true but the MenuSelect function is still showing "there is no menu" error.

Comment: I am trying to use Inspect.exe.

Comment: MenuItems() is giving an empty list

Comment: Please advise on what to do next,I have tried almost everything, maybe this application is not compatible with pywinauto

Comment: I can download and try this app a bit later. Sorry too busy this week.

Comment: That's fine, Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you suggest some other automation tool i can try that uses python.

Comment: See [Automation-tools-ratings](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/UI-Automation-tools-ratings) (there are not only Python tools but all open source desktop GUI automation projects I'm aware of).

Comment: Don't know why you added tag `android`. pywinauto is working on desktop Windows only.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to stack overflow and it suggested me to add that tag so I did, I thought it might attract answers.

Comment: Hi Vasily, Can you also suggest automation tools that use java?

Comment: I'm not in Java world. But you can try Spy++ or Inspect.exe to check wheather your app elements are visible to pywinauto: [The Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Comment: I just found out that the application I am testing it on is a QT based application so I cannot use pywinauto.

Comment: Some actions could be done using pywinauto. Maybe not that nice way like for WPF, but I know guys who automated Qt5 apps. With Qt4 it might be real problem.

Comment: Can you provide a download link for trial version of Baton Media Player? I'd like to take a look.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not authorised to do so because it is company policies to not give out the software like this.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK, let's try to assume it works the same way as WireShark which is based on Qt5. See my answer with the adapted code.

Answer (score 1):

OK, if this is Qt5 app, [WireShark example at lines 58-63](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/wireshark.py#L58) may help you to adapt the code for your app. It should look like this:

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application

# Run a target application
app = Application(backend='uia').start(r"C:\ProgramFiles\BatonMediaPlayer\BatonMediaPlayer.exe")
time.sleep(5)

win = app['Dialog'] # or app.ApproximateMainWindowTitle
win['Help'].select() # exapnd submenu
submenu = app[''] # Dropdown submenu is a top-level window
submenu['About'].select() # or .click_input()
```

Hope it works the same way as for WireShark.

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: But its giving me the NameError: name 'win' is not defined.

Comment: Sorry missed this line: `win = app['Dialog']` (edited the answer).

Comment: File "D:\8samarth\Work\BMPAutomation\Pywinautotry.py", line 9, in <module>
    win['Help'].select() # exapnd submenu
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto-0.5.4-py2.7.egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 243, in __getattr__
    ctrls = _resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto-0.5.4-py2.7.egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 758, in _resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
MatchError: Could not find 'C:\Program Files\BatonMediaPlayer\BatonMediaPlayer.exe' in '[u'Qt5QWindowIcon', u'BatonMediaPlayer', u'BatonMediaPlayerQt5QWindowIcon']'

Comment: I forgot to create an instance of win but when I did I got this error.

Comment: We will probably have to find some other tool because of the backend of this app, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Aha, because you use old pywinauto 0.5.4. Please upgrade it to 0.6.2 in cmd.exe: `pip install -U pywinauto`. After that you have to create `Application(backend='uia')` to use MS UI Automation instead of default Win32 API. It's a new feature starting from 0.6.0.

Comment: What's exactly not working? Did you already give up? Desktop GUI automation is very complicated field, and there are not so many open source tools. Let me wish you a great patience on this way.

Comment: We're working on automatic script generator based on "record-replay" approach (it may help much faster), but the plans are about next year probably.